# WPF Drag&Drop vs manipulation

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, touch

I want to enable Drag'n'Drop of a child control inside a parent that has `IsManipulationEnabled = true`.

When manipulation is enabled, touch events don't get promoted to mouse events. In order to enable promotion, one should handle touch events before manipulation logic steps in (see [example](http://nui.joshland.org/2010/04/why-wont-wpf-controls-work-with-touch.html)). I've tried that and it works... until I call `DoDragDrop` for the first time. Then I no longer receive mouse events. Why?

Here's a minimal code to reproduce the issue. All drag and drop handling was removed for the sake of readability.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" IsManipulationEnabled="True">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="Red" 
                x:Name="Border"
                TouchDown="Border_OnTouchDown"
                MouseDown="Border_OnMouseDown"
                TouchUp="Border_OnTouchUp"
                Width="100" Height="50" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Border_OnTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Border_OnTouchDown");
        e.Handled = true;
        e.TouchDevice.Capture((FrameworkElement)sender);
    }

    private void Border_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Border_OnMouseDown!");
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop((DependencyObject)sender, "", DragDropEffects.All);
    }

    protected override void OnManipulationStarted(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnManipulationStarted");
        base.OnManipulationStarted(e);
    }

    private void Border_OnTouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        ((FrameworkElement)sender).ReleaseTouchCapture(e.TouchDevice);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Border_OnTouchDown
Border_OnMouseDown! <- works first time
Border_OnTouchDown 
Border_OnTouchDown  <- no longer works, no matter how many times I tap
Border_OnTouchDown
Border_OnTouchDown
Border_OnTouchDown
...
```

If I don't call `DoDragDrop` in `MouseDown` - events get promoted as they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for any framework version:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Border_OnTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Border_OnTouchDown");

        IsManipulationEnabled = false;
        e.TouchDevice.Capture(Border);
    }

    private void Border_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Border_OnMouseDown!");
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop((DependencyObject)sender, "", DragDropEffects.All);
    }

    protected override void OnManipulationStarted(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnManipulationStarted");
        base.OnManipulationStarted(e);
    }

    private void Border_OnTouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        Border.ReleaseTouchCapture(e.TouchDevice);
        IsManipulationEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Here we are basically disabling manipulation if the user touched the `Border`. Since drag&drop operation could (and probably would) end outside of the `Border`, we also need to capture the touch input to be sure to receive the `TouchUp` event to re-enable manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a bug in .NET. I had v4.5.2 installed. Now I've installed v4.6 and the problem is no longer reproducible.

I didn't even have to retarget the project to v4.6 or recompile it: just installing the new runtime fixed everything.